# Angular - SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

This is an Angular application deployed on AWS Amplify

The app is deployed successfully, however it renders a white screen, and on the console I receive this message :

[image]

But I don't know how to solve it.

---

This is the service provider :

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
    CONFIG_TOKEN,
    UserService,
    EuiAppConfig,
    UserDetails,
    UserPreferences,
    I18nService,
} from '@eui/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AppStarterService {
    defaultUserPreferences: UserPreferences;

    constructor(
        protected userService: UserService,
        protected i18nService: I18nService,
        @Inject(CONFIG_TOKEN) private config: EuiAppConfig,
        protected http: HttpClient,
    ) {
    }

    start(): Observable<any> {

        return zip(
            this.initUserService().pipe(
                switchMap((userStatus) => {
                    console.log(userStatus);
                    return this.i18nService.init();
                }),
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Fetches user details,
     * create user: UserState object
     * then initialise to the UserService on run time
     */
    initUserService(): Observable<any> {
        return zip(
            this.fetchUserDetails(),
        ).pipe(
            switchMap(([userDetails]) => this.userService.init(userDetails)));
    }

    /**
     * Fetches user details
     */
    private fetchUserDetails(): Observable<UserDetails> {
        const moduleCoreApi = this.config.modules.core;
        const url = `${moduleCoreApi.base}${moduleCoreApi.userDetails}`;
        const user = { userId: 'anonymous' };

        if (!url) {

            return of(user);
        }
        return this.http.get<UserDetails>(url);
    }
}
```

And from that code, this is the "**const moduleCoreApi = this.config.modules.core;**" and the "**moduleCoreApi.base**" part

```
import { ModulesConfig } from '@eui/core';

export const MODULES: ModulesConfig = {
    core: {
        base: '/api',
    }
};
```

This is the **environment.prod.ts**

```
import { EuiEnvConfig } from '@eui/core';

export const environment: EuiEnvConfig = {
    production: true,
    enableDevToolRedux: false,
    envDynamicConfig: {
        uri: '/assets/env-json-config.json',
        deepMerge: true,
        merge: ['modules'],
    },
};
```

And from that code, this the **env-json-config.json**

```
{
    "modules": {
        "core": {
            "userDetails": "/user-details"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The HTTP request to [this URL](https://main.d3inc23hrcazy1.amplifyapp.com/api/user-details) returns an HTML response instead of JSON value. This is why you get the error. You need to make a call to an API endpoint that returns JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been solved thanks to @Harun Yilmaz by updating the api endpoint to this :

```
return this.http.get(url,{responseType: 'text'});
```

Comment: What if it's a post/put request