# Angular .NET Core: http get not hitting controller method

Tags: c#, angular, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm working on an Angular application which uses a .NET Core back end with EF to learn Angular. The solution was generated by selecting the Angular and ASP.NET Core project template in Visual Studio 2022. My controllers were scaffolded by selecting the option API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework.

There're two models. Employee and Salary. Each one has a controller. Namely EmployeesController and SalariesController. There's a service class which accesses the controllers. When the user clicks a button on the first page the employees page loads. This works correctly. The user can click a link next to each employee to view their salary. The code for the Salaries page is identical to that of the employees page. But when I click the link the page loads without any data. When I debug the action method on the controller doesn't get hit.

Here's my Employees controller.

```
namespace EmployeesAngular.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
    { 
        private readonly EmployeesAngularServerContext _context;

        public EmployeesController(EmployeesAngularServerContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Employee>>> GetEmployee()
        {
            return await _context.Employee.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Salaries controller

```
namespace EmployeesAngular.Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SalariesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly EmployeesAngularServerContext _context;

        public SalariesController(EmployeesAngularServerContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Salary>>> GetSalary()
        {
            return await _context.Salary.ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the app.component.html file.

```
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Employee Details</h3>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <button routerLink="employees" class="m-1 btn btn-light btn-outline-primary" Button>Employees</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Here's the employees.component.html file.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Department</th>
      <th>Date Of Joining</th>
      <th>Total Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dataItem of EmployeeList">
      <td>{{dataItem.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{dataItem.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{dataItem.department}}</td>
      <td>{{dataItem.joinDate}}</td>
      <td>{{dataItem.totalSalary}}</td>
      <td><a routerLink="/salaries" routerLinkActive="active" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">View Salary Components</a></td>
      <td><a routerLink="/editEmployee" routerLinkActive="active" ariaCurrentWhenActive="page">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the code for the salaries.component.html file.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Basic</th>
      <th>Allowance</th>
      <th>Bonus</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dataItem of SalaryList">
      <td>{{dataItem.basic}}</td>
      <td>{{dataItem.allowance}}</td>
      <td>{{dataItem.bonus}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the employees.component.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiserviceService } from '../apiservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
 })
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: ApiserviceService) { }

  EmployeeList: any = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshEmpList();
  }

  refreshEmpList() {
    this.service.getEmployeeList().subscribe(data => {
      this.EmployeeList = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Here's the salaries.component.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiserviceService } from '../apiservice.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-salaries',
  templateUrl: './salaries.component.html',
  styleUrl: './salaries.component.css'
})
export class SalariesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private service: ApiserviceService) {
}

  SalaryList: any = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.refreshSalary();
  }

  refreshSalary() {
    this.service.getSalaryList().subscribe(data => {
      this.SalaryList = data;
    });
  }
}
```

This is my service called the apiservice.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
 
export class ApiserviceService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployeeList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('employees');
  }

  getSalaryList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('salaries');
  }
}
```

This is how routing is done in the app-routing-module.ts file.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'employees', component: EmployeesComponent },
  { path: 'salaries', component: SalariesComponent },
  { path: 'editEmployee', component: EditEmployeeComponent },
];
```

When I click the salary link and observe the console under developer tools in the browser I see an error saying

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid

I searched for this error and tried to implement the suggested fixes. As mentioned in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73908526/angular-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-doctype-is-not-valid-json) I modified the code to look like this.

```
getSalaryList(): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>('salaries', { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

This gives me a compiler error saying

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'

In the responseType property it also says that

> No overload matches this call

As suggested in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222464/syntax-error-in-angular-app-unexpected-token/57021035#57021035) I tried to change base href in the Index.html page like this but that didn't work either.

```
<base href="/">

to

<base href=".">
```

Based on another answer I modified the code in the service class like this.

```
getSalaryList(): Observable<any[]> {
    const httpOptions: Object = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Accept': 'text/html',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
      }),
      responseType: 'text'
    };

    return this.http.get<any[]>('salaries', httpOptions);
}
```

This also doesn't hit the controller action method. And gives me an error in the browser console saying

> NG0900: Error trying to diff...Only arrays and iterables are allowed.

I looked at several other answers to similar questions. But the responses seems to be incomplete. Most questions don't have a selected answer and the suggestions on the answers do not seem to work for this problem. So I'm posting this question.

Although I tried various suggestions because they're given in answers I'm mystified as to why the code doesn't work for Salaries while it works for Employees.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you get when you hit the controller explicitly with some other tool, for example postman?

Comment: @Adrian Kokot, I tried with Postman. For the employees URL I'm getting the data correctly as the response. But for the salaries URL it gives the Index.html page.

Comment: So the problem is not in the client but in the server. Are you sure the controller is loaded correctly? What route are you trying to hit exactly? Are you using some kind of automatic controller loading or manual? Which version of .net are you using?

Comment: @Adrian Kokot, I don't get what you mean by controller loading. So far in .net core applications I've created the project in Visual Studio, added my code if necessary, and run it. I hadn't changed any default settings. The route I'm trying to hit are given in the service class. The controller class defines the route with the Route attribute as [Route("[controller]")] so in the service class I'm giving the URL as 'salaries' (controller name) to the http get call. I'm using .net core 8. Things work with the employees controller. So I don't know why they don't work with the salaries controller.

Comment: well, if you use the default setup of everyhing then there's no reason it should not work. Maybe weird question, but did you rebuild the project after adding the new controller?

Comment: Does your salary controller got hit from postman? Whats the details of ` _context.Salary.ToListAsync()`?

Comment: @Adrian Kokot, No, rebuilding the project doesn't help either.

Comment: @Md Farid, The salary controller doesn't get hit from postman either. The details of the method call: There's a model called Salary. I'm using EF Core. That's why I'm calling the records in the Salary table with _context.

Comment: While calling from postman what error you are getting or what error code?

Comment: @Md Farid, While calling from postman I'm getting status 200 OK but it doesn't return the data. It returns the Index.html page. The Employees controller returns the data if called from postman.

Comment: Have you checked your network calls using your browser developer tools. When your angular website loads, press F12 and your browser dev tools will open. Find the network tab and then navigate to one of your routes that should hit an end point. You should see what Api call was made. Make sure the url matches your back end url.

Comment: Also, why are you setting the content type to text/plain and the accept to html. Content type should be application/json and maybe just leave the accept off. I think this is why you are getting the error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669615/angular-http-post-request-content-type-from-text-plain-to-application-json

Answer (score 0):

### What is the problem?

your angular and asp.net are running on different ports and when you write this line

```
this.http.get<any[]>('employees');
```

your request will try to get employees through angular port `https://localhost:4200/employees`  and angular will resolve this as `EmployeesComponent` and not to call the backend

### Fix the problem

First, let's distinguish Between your API routes and the component routes. Make your API run on `/api/Employees` and `/api/salaries` by changing the following line in controller files

```
Route("api/[controller]")]
```

Second, we need to tell angular any route is start with `/api/**` forward it to the backend, this Can be done by open the file `employeesangular.client > src > proxy.conf.js` and remove `/weatherForecast` and add `/api/**`

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api/**"
    ],
    target,
    secure: false
  }
]
```

Finally, change your service to use the correct route

```
export class ApiserviceService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployeeList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('/api/Employees');
  }

  getSalaryList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('/api/salaries');
  }
}
```